# Setting timeout for jeditable operations?

Tags: timeout, datatables, jeditable

I'm using the jeditable plugin for Datatables.  I have a page set up with a table that passes the submitted add form to a .java class to process, and has the fnShowError parameter set to display a failure message.

The operations the add handler does take a while, and sometimes the add will succeed but I will get the fnSHowError message anyways, likely because of a timeout.  Is there a way to specify a timeout length for the add function?